# implementing chat feature with already registered users

Tags: android, chat

I know there are already some topics about implementing chat feature but this is a little bit different.

Imagine I have a website with 1000 users. I am writing an android application which user can login and access its account settings and blah & blah all using web services.

When user logins, the first thing which appears is the list of his friends.

The question is: I want to implement a chat feature so that when the user clicks one of his friends, a p2p chat window appear.

How can I achieve this? Is there any api to do so?

Do not forget users are already registered on my website (mysql) so he shouldn't register for a second time to use the chat feature. Am i clear?.

Answer (score 2):

There are many api's that you can use, for example Quickblox and Scringo. They can also be integrated with 3-rd party (your own backend server). For Scringo, the free one, check this out: 
http://www.scringo.com/docs/android-guides/popular/setup-a-chat-client/